# What are the advantages/disadvantages of if/else vs if/elif/raise

Tags: python

I have something similar to this in a pull request:

```py
def my_func(my_var: str) -> str:
    if my_var == 'val1':
        return '1'
    elif my_var == 'val2':
        return '2'
    else:
        raise ValueError('Unsupported value')
```

The value of my_var is ensured to be either 'val1' or 'val2' in a different place of the code. For that reason, I have been suggested to remove the raise statement and leave only a if/else:

```py
def my_func(my_var: str) -> str:
    if my_var == 'val1':
        return '1'
    else:
        return '2'
```

The reason given is that the raise is not required as the value is checked in a different place, and it may be confusing/unnecessary.

I don't like that option because:

1. It is not impossible that the value check of my_var that happens on a different place changes over time, which would make this code to be potentially wrong as it will handle any new values using the else part of the conditional.
2. It doesn't explicitly state the else value ('val2'), as it would be just an else without equality.

What are other advantages/disadvantages of either case? Are there any better alternatives?

I want more info to decide the best alternative, as this case comes frequently in our code reviews.

Comment: Without seeing the whole code I don't know how anyone could know.  But there's also the single responsibility principle, which might suggest that checking `my_var` belongs in _one_ place.  In any case if `my_var` is *really* just going to hold one of two values, I'd use an enum (yes, python has them! and they're underused) and *state* that.

Comment: Example 1 is good if you want to debug the code and want to return an error if you get the wrong input, you should consider outputting my_var if you get a ValueError, for debugging purpose. Example 2 is good if you don't want the code to fail, and you accepting 2 as output if you get the wrong input.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any better alternatives?

If you have variable which can have limited number of values then it might be represented using [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html). You need powe to dictate what type of argument your function is accepting in order to use this approach.

> It is not impossible that the value check of my_var that happens on a
> different place changes over time, which would make this code to be
> potentially wrong as it will handle any new values using the else part
> of the conditional.

You need to **unrevokably** decide who is responsible for checking that (where check should be). Repeating exactly *same* check might be considered infringement of DRY rule.

Answer (score 1):

As you said the function that calls your `my_func` can change over time and start passing different values.

What you could do additionally in your code is to add `Literal` typing for your parameter

```py
from typing import Literal

def my_func(my_var: Literal['val1', 'val2']) -> str:
    if my_var == 'val1':
        return '1'
    elif my_var == 'val2':
        return '2'
    else:
        raise ValueError('Unsupported value')
```

That way developers will have highlighted code if they will try to call your function with different parameter:

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting alternative I didn't know about. Wouldn't this break the DRY principle as @Daweo mentioned it the responsibility of validating the value is in a different place?

Comment: I would say that type hinting itself wouldn't be a breaking of DRY principle as it doesn't affect code execution but rather gives hints for other devs, linters, IDEs, etc. so you can avoid the problem in the future where someone changes the function that validates values and pass not supported value.
I think that @Daweo suggestion to use `enum` is great. 
When it comes to validation itself and where it takes place it depends on the behaviour of those functions.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code, you expect the value of "my_var" to be either "val1" or "val2". However, if the value provided is neither of the above, it raises an error. It is a good approach when expecting input from users. Rule number one, Never trust user input.

On the second function, you're only interested in the provided value "val1", otherwise, anything else is treated as "val2".

There are several instances that require either of the above functions.
Example 1:
You have a program where a user should choose a menu either cheese or chocolate. Here you have to apply function one since any other menu provided by the user will not be existing. The user will be limited to only those two options.

Example 2:
You have a program that asks a user whether to proceed or not. Here the options are, either reply with one to continue or reply with anything else to decline. That is where function2 comes into application.

Comment: But we have a value checker somewhere else, that will check the validity of the current values ('val1' and 'val2') so, in theory, this function should not receive anything else (unless that checker changes).

Comment: If you are 100% sure it is only val1 and val2 arriving at the function after validation, then there is no need of raising an error since it will be of no use.